# when using Sequelize, how to write bitwise(or) operatioin?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, bitwise-operators

Sequelize / Postgres

**column reasoncodes contains string values like these.

> > 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0**

The idea is to fetch this value and replace it so it becomes bit
then compare this with a value string that the frontend has passed (0001000000000)

This works in Postgres.

```
select * from schema.table
where cast(cast(replace(reasoncodes, ',', '') as bit(13)) & cast('0001000000000' as bit(13)) as integer) > 0
and  table.id = 1885
```

How to convert this where clause into Sequelize syntax is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'Sequelize.literal', e.g:

```
TableName.findAll({
 where: {
   [Op.and]: [
       Sequelize.literal('cast(cast(replace(reasoncodes, ',', '') as bit(13)) & cast('0001000000000' as bit(13)) as integer) > 0')
   ]
 }
})
```